# How to get rid of "Device or resource busy" during setup of loop device?

Tags: error-handling

What could be the reason for `Device or resource busy` during setup of a sparse file with `losetup /dev/loop4 /path/to/sparse_file.img` when `losetup -a` shows that no loop devices are in use and the system has been rebooted? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 with `util-linux` 2.20.1.

I certainly experienced this once after a boot when the kernel was stuck (so that no even <kbd>Strg</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S-Abf</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> would make the machine reboot).

Comment: I don't have the time resouces to do this now. Do you have specific interest in the bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to reinstall my kernel image, i.e. package `linux-image-x.x.x` with `dpkg` - I still don't understand how the resource/file could have been busy after a reboot...